# using date parameter in c# crystal report with month only

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to use date parameter with month only?

ex: i need to print a data for the whole month of June, i want to sort and print it by month, no date and year

(working in C#)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a numeric parameter `{?Month}` , using the 'Field Explorer', with values 1-12 and the corresponding descriptions (e.g. 1 is January).

Next, create a record-selection formula that resembles:

```
 // calculate the beginning of the month and the last of month (add a month to the first day of the month, then subtract a day)
{table.date} IN Date( Year(DataDate), {?Month}, 1) TO Date( DateAdd("m", 1, Date( Year(DataDate), {?Month}, 1)) - 1 )
```

Comment: should i create the numeric parameter under in parameter field?

Comment: how about if i want to sort it by month and my chosen year? is that possible?

Comment: Sort what by year?  The parameter or the data?